# How to prevent mail from going spam?

Tags: php, email

below is my header to sent the mail to the user -

```
$to='example@example.com';
$recipient='example@example.com';
$headers = "From: noreply@xxx.com" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Sender: <" . "$to" . ">\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: <" . "$to" . ">\r\n";
$headers .= "Error-To: <" . "$to" . ">\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";

mail("$recipient", "$subj", "$body", "$headers")
```

But the problem occurs when my go in spam (in gmail)
gmail said:-

```
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - myexoticfriends.myexoticfriends.com
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - gmail.com
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [510 32003] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - myexoticfriends.myexoticfriends.com
X-Source: /usr/bin/php
X-Source-Args: /usr/bin/php /home/exotic/public_html/test/test.php 
X-Source-Dir: myexoticfriends.com:/public_html/test
```

Comment: @Quentin, no this is not duplication I saw it.

Comment: Then did you tried to use the solution provided in that question...?

Comment: @Sudhir, already tried b4 posting this question.

Comment: I think he's encountering some (recent) changes to how Gmail determines what is spam. I don't have a link to an announcement of these changes, but I've been dealing with this too at work. A few weeks ago, mail that normally sailed though suddenly, well, didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gmail: keeps on searching and tracking the list of the mails that are send/receive.

If you keep on sending the mails with same subject and content then it will automatically put mails in spam, plus, if the CTR ratio means the click ratio of your mail is less, then too Gmail send them in spam, don't send the mails in bulk.

Answer (score 4):

Try using a different STMP server, if you have a Gmail account you can try using SwiftMailer. http://swiftmailer.org/. Also, keep in mind your server's IP address might be listed in some DNS or SMTP blacklists, try looking up your IP in http://www.dnsbl.info/

If you're sending lots of emails, though, I'd recommend you use a mailing service. We've used http://postmarkapp.com/ and it works beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to share headers from one of the messages that was received but went to spam, someone from the Postmark team would be able to share some insight into what's likely going on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send your mail via a different SMTP as your domain has been flagged as spammy. You can contact gmail if you feel this is an error.